# No action was found on the controller 'Depts' that matches the request. webApi C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have web api with three methods it was running absolutely very fine a week before but I don't understand why it is not running now. I am trying from last 3 days and desperately looking for help.

when testing on browser for
`/api/Depts/Get/`
`/api/Depts/GetDeptById/2`

worked fine but tested for 
`api/Depts/GetDeptByCompany/'abc'`

Throwing an error No action was found on the controller 'Attorneys' that matches the request. webApi  C# .NET

weapi.Config file

```
namespace Test_Dept
{
  public static class WebApiConfig
  {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //// Attribute routing
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          // routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
     }
   }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace Test_Dept.Controllers
{
  public class DeptsController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Dept> Get()
    {
        return DeptRepository.GetAllDepts();
    }
    [HttpGet]
            public Dept GetDeptById(int id)
    {
        Dept Att = DeptRepository.GetDeptById(id);
        if(Att==null)
           throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        else
           return Att;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Dept> GetDeptByCompany(string company)
    {
        var Att = DeptRepository.GetDeptByCompany(company);
        if (Att.ToList().Count == 0)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        else
            return Att;
    }
```

Repository

```
namespace Test_Dept.Models
{
  public class DeptRepository
  {
    public static List<Dept> GetAllDepts()
    {
        DeptEntities dataContext = new DeptEntities();
        var query = from dept in dataContext.Depts select dept;
        return query.ToList();
    }
    public static Dept GetDeptById(int id)
    {
        DeptEntities dataContext = new DeptEntities();
        var query = (from dept in dataContext.Depts where Dept.ID == id select dept).SingleOrDefault();
        return query;
    }
    public static List<Dept> GetDeptByCompany(string company)
    {
        DeptEntities dataContext = new DeptEntities();
        var query = (from dept in dataContext.Depts where Dept.Company == company select Dept);
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo in your question, but `Deptss` has a double "s"

Comment: Thanks but no it is a typo ..not working

Comment: Do you have an `Attorneys` controller? Your URLs don't have anything to do with the phrase "Attorneys", so there's obviously some routing problem here. Perhaps post your entire route config, or at least the portion that mentions "Attorneys"

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around `abc`

Comment: I tested by removing quotes getting same error.

Comment: I tested like api/Depts/GetDeptByCompany?company='abc' then I am getting an error at return Att in the GetDeptByCompany function .

Comment: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

Comment: need to remove quotes and test the web api method like api/Depts/GetDeptByCompany?company=abc and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mention of "attorneys" in your question is a typo. The parameter name in your route needs to match the parameter name in your controller action. You existing route will only work for controller actions where the parameter name is id. If you want the url `api/Depts/GetDeptByCompany/abc` to work (notice there are no quotes around the parameter). Then you could add a route such as

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "CompanyApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{company}");
```

If you are using Web API 2 then yoou may prefer attribute routes and you can do the following on the controller action.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{controller}/{action}/{company}")]
public List<Dept> GetDeptByCompany(string company)
```

Comment: what if I have more than one method for Get like GetDeptByCompany,GetDeptByCity then how can  I add this in config file

Answer (score 0):

need to remove quotes and test the web api method like
api/Depts/GetDeptByCompany?company=abc and it worked. Thank you every one for helping me to find the answer you thoughts and comments helped me to solve this.